# Css issue: trying to place image and text in parent div

Tags: html, css, materialize

I know I'm missing something easy here but I've hit a wall and need a hand. I'm trying to achieve the following: [image]

I'm using materialze CSS for the use of their grid.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            <h3 id="ipad-image"><img src="<%= asset_path('Main copy.png') %>"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
            <h3 class="center">box 2 text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas what I should do?

---

This is the result.

[image]

Comment: What is exatly your problem? What happen with the provided HTML?

Comment: Please add a https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see exactly what you did.

Comment: Your image is inside one column and the text inside another. Your image overflows the column.
Also, there is no way on earth that this image should be inside an H3 tag.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't mean to leave that h3 tag there, my last attempt was to go back to basics and have two h3 text elements and split them on the page. The image wasn't meant to go inside it sorry. The same happens without the h3 tag also. Any suggestions on how to stop the image from overflowing into the other columns?

Answer (score 0):

try this.. it might work
1) remove h3 tag from image(img itself is a block level element)
2) you might need to define the width of image 
3)

```
<div class="col s4">
            <h3 class="pull-right">box 2 text</h3>
 </div>
```